# How to declare and use a jasper parameter in a sub report without declaring it in my main report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'd like to use parameters for a sub report (footer).

Is there a simple way to declare a parameter and using it only in the sub report ?

I have already a working solution, but I have to :

- declare my parameters in the main report
- declare my parameters in the main report as a sub report parameter
- declare my parameters in the sub report to finally being able to use it

I work on xml files directly, without iReport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, we can't. It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since parameters can be of any class imaginable you could always wrap your parameters in other classes. In Java, for example, you could use a  `Map`. This way you need to declare only one parameter for your sub report and access each sub report parameter in the map through the appropriate getters of your wrapping class.

As an example for a generic `HashMap`:
declare like this

```
<parameter name="subreportParameters" class="java.util.HashMap" isForPrompting="false"/>
```

and use like this

```
<![CDATA[$P{subreportParameters}.get("YOUR_PARAMETER_KEY") ]]>
```

The downside to having only one parameter is reduced readability in your sub report. This might be an acceptable trade-off for small sub reports like footers.